# how to get android app to allow user to drag screen up and down with their finger

Tags: java, android, scroll

I am working on an android app, where I would like the user to be able to drag the screen up and down to see the fields form fields. this is hard right now because the keyboard gets in the way. Is this something I am just looking over? As you can see the keyboard covers most of the fields. I just want the user to be able to drag the screen up to see the lower fields.

[image]

Comment: put your layout in ScrollView also in manifest file for that particular activity adjustviewpane="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using some of these:

`android:windowSoftInputMode=["adjustUnspecified", "adjustResize", "adjustPan"] >`

Read more here about each attribute http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ScrollView` with `android:fillViewport="true"` so that your content still fills the screen up.